# Why i get error when i try to create an article for a child user?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Here is the problem:
When I try to create article for the user itself, it works. But when I try to create an article as the parent of the child user instead of the child user itself, I get a validation error. I am trying to make sure the parent is the authenticated user. How can I solve this issue?

```
class User(AbstractUser,PermissionsMixin):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True)
    username =models.CharField(max_length=40,unique=True,default='undefinedusername')
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self',on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
    
class Article(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='articles')
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=250)


class ArticleCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('id','author','caption')

    def validate(self, attrs):
        attrs = super().validate(attrs)
        if attrs['author'].id != self.context['request'].user.pk:
            raise ValidationError('Unauthorized Request')
        elif attrs['author'].parent.id == self.context['request'].user.pk:
            return attrs
        elif (attrs.get('author').parent != None) and (attrs.get('parent').id != self.context['request'].user.pk):
            raise ValidationError('Unauthorized Request')
        return attrs
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the issue. I had to change the validate functions in this way:

Changing validate function to this:

```
    def validate(self, attrs):
        attrs = super().validate(attrs)
        if attrs['author'].id == self.context['request'].user.pk:
            return attrs
        elif attrs.get('author').parent.id == self.context['request'].user.pk:
            return attrs
        raise ValidationError('Unauthorized Request')
```

Let me explain why I faced issues:

If any of the IF conditions were true and others were false,i would get false so i had to change the validation check to check all the conditions and then give error if none matched.

Why i eliminated some of the functions is simple:

```
      1-  elif attrs['author'].parent.id == self.context['request'].user.pk:
            return attrs
      2-  elif (attrs.get('author').parent != None) and (attrs.get('parent').id != self.context['request'].user.pk):
            raise ValidationError('Unauthorized Request')
```

-Number 1 was just clutter

-In number 2 , i did not have to check if user had parent. If the parent had an authentication , validation could be passed. Checking if parent exists or not may be a good argument but it is prone to errors.